# Git commands with emacsclient expect vim input

Tags: git, vim-emulation

I'm using emacsclient.  When I use `git glog` or `git rebase -i` in a shell within my emacs session, I see output that expects me to be able to scroll (and to exit with `:q`).  I cannot exit this buffer, and interaction with it is challenging since it is somewhat mangled.

What setting do I need to change in my default editor or git settings for this unusable state to not arise?

Comment: Did you check the values of environment variables $EDITOR and $VISUAL?

Comment: I don’t know these. What should they be for reasonable behavior?

Comment: You can set $VISUAL from Emacs by running the following sexp: `(setenv "VISUAL" "emacsclient")`.